# What's wrong with this constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class Ball
{
    public:
    int i,j,iplus,jplus;
    Ball(int i , int j , int iplus , int jplus)
    {   iplus=1; 
        jplus=1; 
        i=400;
        j=300;
    }
};
int main()
{
        Ball toop(Ball);
}
```

I get the following error:

> request for member ‘jplus’ in ‘toop’, which is of non-class type ‘Ball(Ball)’

Comment: What is this piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: What is `Ball toop(Ball);` supposed to do? Because at the moment it does _nothing_ but declare a function that you never use. [So I'm pretty sure that this is not your real code.](http://codepad.org/euRwBpVH)

Comment: why declare parameters to the constructor but not use the values?

Comment: also your parameters and private members are the same name, that's going to cause confusion

Comment: Your constructor makes me sad :(

Comment: @Geoff: my bet: he wants default construction but someone taught him he should always accept a parameter to for each field. [Cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)

Answer (score 3):

```
Ball toop(Ball);
```

should be something like:

```
Ball toop(10,20,30,40);
```

Accidentally(as most users), you have created is called as the **[Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)** in C++.
It does not create a object as you think it does, instead it declares a function which takes `Ball` as an input parameter and returns `Ball`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Ball toop(Ball); //function declaration
```

It declares a function `toop` which takes one argument of type `Ball`, and returns `Ball`. It doesn't define an object.

I think you wanted to write something like this:

```
Ball toop(1,2,3,4); //object definition
```

Apart from that you should be using member-initialization-list in the constructor as:

```
Ball(int i , int j , int iplus , int jplus) 
    : i(i), j(j), iplus(iplus), jplus(jplus)
{ //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ its called member-initialization-list
}
```

Here, the syntax `i(i)` looks weird, but it means the other outer `i` is initialized with the inner `i`. The inner `i` is the constructor parameter-name, and the outer `i` is the member of the class, as shown below:

```
 : i (i), j(j), iplus(iplus), jplus(jplus)
   ^  ^
   |  parameter-name
   class-member-name
```

Similar explanation is for others as well :  `j(j), iplus(iplus), jplus(jplus)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Ball toop(Ball);
```

declares a function.

You didn't show the rest of your code, but it says

```
 toop.jplus
```

somewhere else. That doesn't fly, because toop is a function pointer (non-class type). A function type doesn't support the *member access operator* (`.`) hence the error message.

```
Ball toop(1,2,3,4);
int y = toop.jplus;
```

would work. Although I'm mighty interested what you are trying to achieve in the constructor :)

I suggest:

```
class Ball
{
  public:
    int i,j,iplus,jplus;
    Ball() : jplus(1), iplus(1), i(400), j(300) 
    {   
    }
};
int main()
{
        Ball toop; // **not** toop()!
        int test = toop.j; // 300
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to post your full testcase. [The code you posted is perfectly valid.](http://codepad.org/euRwBpVH)

What your `main` presumably *really* looks like is:

```
int main() {
   Ball toop(Ball);
   toop.jplus = 2; // or something
}
```

Except when you tried to create `toop`, you actually just declared a function called `toop` that takes and returns objects of type `Ball`. I'm not quite sure why you've done that.

To use your constructor and create an object, use code that looks like this:

```
Ball toop(1,2,3,4);
```

---

And please, next time, post an *actual* testcase that reproduces the problem. You were lucky that:

- the error message gave the issue away
- I'm very good

Answer (score 0):

```
Ball toop(Ball);
```

is wrong because you declared it with 4 parameters, so you should pass the four parameters. Like Your constructor is taking 4 integers as parameter so pass 4 integer values

Like

```
Ball toop(0,0,0,0);
```

Or

```
int x=0;
Ball toop(x,x,x,x);
```